# having a flex child scale and cover all other children inside container on click

Tags: css

I have a flex container with some children that are `<divs>`. `onClick` I want the clicked cube to scale and animate to fill all the available width and height, but where I'm stuck is I would also like it to overlap all the other children so that it ends up being the only one visible.

I want it to break out of the document flow with I assume `position:absolute` but I also want it to preserve its starting coordinates as it expands, so setting any `top` or other property is not my desired result

How is this achievable? Sandbox is linked below

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-water-9q9t4o?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Could you put your code into your question (so that if the sandbox disappears future readers understand the basis of the problem).

Comment: I am not clear what effect is required as the overall picture is not square (the squares could be in a single line on a wide viewport, and in a single column on a narrow one and other layouts in between).  Is the clicked square to expand to cover everything else ending up as a rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the solution here [link to sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-hypatia-e9s5cp?file=/src/App.js). Used position absolute but not the `top` property as you wanted. I have pasted the code below for quick reference. Removed styles for `item` inside your css since you are providing it inside the component. I have also added **key** attribute to the `li` element as React would want you to add that. To not cause multiple `useEffect()` calls I have added `[expand]` dependency.

**Latest edit:** It looked like the earlier solution worked only if the height of the flex container is less than the width. So if you resize the screen such that its height becomes greater than the width, the solution fails. So to solve that, I have updated the code below and also the sandbox where you can checkout by changing screen sizes. Depending on whether the height of the flex container is greater than its width or not, you have to adjust the height properties as you can see in the code. You check that condition inside useEffect. I have commented the added codes as well. That's it!

**Edit:** *How does it work?*

When you click on the child element(`li`), it is absolutely positioned but relative to its parent container so it gets automatically positioned to the top-left corner of the parent `ul`.

Since the container width is set to `100vw`, it takes the full width of the viewport and that becomes the `min-width` of the **itemExpand** since we want it's width to cover the container. Now due to `aspectRatio:'1'`, the height of the itemExpand will be equal to its width but we don't want that. So we set `max-height` of the itemExpand to the actual height of the container since unlike width, the `auto` value for height will be determined by its child elements. So now the height and width of the itemExpand becomes equal to that of the container which was the result we wanted.

Now what happen if we set explicit `width` and `height` for the parent container, let's say `width: 400px` and `height: 600px`. Remember again that there is no explicit width and height for the child `li` so it defaults to `auto`. In this case you can change the style of **itemExpand** to `max-width: width` and `min-height: height`. Here we are never letting the width to exceed 400px which will be caused by `aspect-ratio: 1` since we are setting the `min-height` of the `li` to 600px. Now that will again change if the width of the container is greater than its height. That's all for the explanation!

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(null);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);
  
  // added for responsive
  const [heightGreater, setHeightGreater] = useState(true);


  // ref for container element
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  const handleExpand = (d) => {
    if (expand === d) {
      setExpand(null);
    } else {
      setExpand(d);
    }
  };

  const item = {
    aspectRatio: "1",
    width: "10rem",
    backgroundColor: "red",
    transition: "all .5s ease",
    maxHeight: "10rem",
    maxWidth: "10rem"
  };

  const itemExpand = {
    aspectRatio: "1",
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "green",
    transition: "all .5s ease",
    transformOrigin: "center",
    // added for responsive
    minWidth: heightGreater ? "auto" : width,
    maxHeight: heightGreater ? "auto" : height,
    minHeight: heightGreater ? height : "auto",
    maxWidth: heightGreater ? width : "auto",
  };

  // set height and width of child element to parent height and width
  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref.current.offsetHeight);
    setWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth);
    
    // added for responsive
    if (height > width) {
      setHeightGreater(true);
    } else {
      setHeightGreater(false);
    }
  },[expand]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul className="container" ref={ref}>
        {data.map((d, i) => (
          <li key={i}
            style={expand === d ? itemExpand : item}
            onClick={() => handleExpand(d)}
          ></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

/* set explicit height and width for the container*/
.container {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.expand {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi, would it be possible to have a little more explanation of how this works - I couldn't see how the flexed container maintains its structure if the clicked element is removed from the flow.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth, I have added explanation on how it works. As for your question do you mean how the child element is able to fit the container height and width after its removal due to absolute positioning?

Comment: What I meant was that the dimensions of the parent change when you take an item out so it may not have the same shape or size that it had originally.

Comment: Hi, @AHaworth, yes the flex container may not have to same size as it had originally since its height value is set to `auto`. Setting an explicit height can retain the original size since width has explicit value already and the solution will still work. Since OP hasn't specified if he wants to retain the original structure, I have answered with respect to container height having an `auto` value.